# A few processes taking far longer than the others during multiprocessing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I need to do an expensive computation on each element of a large list of items in a production environment (AWS). In one use case, the list has ~50k elements and each computation takes ~500ms. They vary, but none should take more than 1.5s. Both the input and the computation change over time, so this needs to be done regularly. I've successfully broken up the task using multiprocessing, and for much smaller lists I see the expected, nearly-linear speedup in computation time. However, using every recipe for multiprocessing I've tried, I observe a large discrepancy between the duration of the fastest process and the slowest one. For example, I may do something like:

```
def worker(compute_func, queue_in, queue_out):
    while True:
        queue_out.put(compute_func(queue_in.get(True)))
        queue_in.task_done()


def multiprocess_task(input):
    # divide by 2 because using more than the number of cores 
    # doesn't actually speed anything up
    num_procs = multiprocessing.cpu_count() / 2
    queue_in = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    queue_out = multiprocessing.Queue()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_procs, worker, (compute_func, queue_in, queue_out))

    for item in input:
        queue_in.put(item)

    queue_in.join()
    pool.close()

    return process_output(queue_out)
```

I've also done this using `pool.map` and `pool.imap_unordered`, both by mapping the function onto the input list and also by manually breaking the input into chunks and mapping so each process just works on one chunk (with a modified version of my computation), and for imap_unordered, both with a chunk size of 1 and other numbers (10, 100). I get the same result each time:

For a while, `top` looks like this:

```
  4171 george    20   0 7191344 6.439g   2380 R 100.1 10.9   6:29.44 python                                                                                                                                                             
  4172 george    20   0 7190064 6.438g   2380 R 100.1 10.9   6:21.86 python                                                                                                                                                             
  4173 george    20   0 7202608 6.450g   2388 R 100.1 10.9   6:30.23 python                                                                                                                                                             
  4178 george    20   0 7200300 6.447g   2388 R 100.1 10.9   6:30.30 python                                                                                                                                                             
  4180 george    20   0 7190060 6.438g   2380 R 100.1 10.9   6:29.72 python                                                                                                                                                             
  4181 george    20   0 7191596 6.439g   2436 R 100.1 10.9   6:30.60 python                                                                                                                                                             
  4187 george    20   0 7191084 6.439g   2388 R 100.1 10.9   6:30.55 python                                                                                                                                                             
  4188 george    20   0 7190316 6.438g   2380 R 100.1 10.9   6:31.06 python                                                                                                                                                             
  4174 george    20   0 7190320 6.438g   2380 R  99.8 10.9   6:29.87 python                                                                                                                                                             
  4175 george    20   0 7190576 6.438g   2388 R  99.8 10.9   6:29.71 python                                                                                                                                                             
  4176 george    20   0 7190576 6.438g   2380 R  99.8 10.9   6:22.57 python                                                                                                                                                             
  4177 george    20   0 7190832 6.439g   2388 R  99.8 10.9   6:30.19 python                                                                                                                                                             
  4179 george    20   0 7192364 6.440g   2380 R  99.8 10.9   6:30.22 python                                                                                                                                                             
  4182 george    20   0 7191340 6.439g   2380 R  99.8 10.9   6:30.23 python                                                                                                                                                             
  4183 george    20   0 7190316 6.438g   2380 R  99.8 10.9   6:30.06 python                                                                                                                                                             
  4184 george    20   0 7203372 6.451g   2436 R  99.8 10.9   6:30.90 python                                                                                                                                                             
  4185 george    20   0 7204652 6.452g   2336 R  99.8 10.9   6:30.99 python                                                                                                                                                             
  4186 george    20   0 7190060 6.438g   2388 R  99.8 10.9   6:30.90 python
```

After about 20 minutes, only ~half the processes are still running. After 40 minutes, there's still one python process running.

I was under the impression that both `imap_unordered` and the `Queue` recipe I pasted above would apply a process to the next element of input as soon as a process is available, so I don't understand how that could be happening.

The worker does not read or write to disk, but `compute_func` is a `partial` of a Cython-defined class method of an object loaded into memory by the parent process.

As a final note, I am a novice at parallelization, so please forgive (and correct!) me if I've used any vocabulary incorrectly.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are the items equal on how expensive the computation is? If you have 11 items, 10 of them takes 1 min to process and 1 takes 10 mins you're not going to get below 10 mins with parallelization.

Comment: @niemmi they vary but not by that much. Editing original post for some clarity.

Comment: I don't have any idea what the issue is, but perhaps you could add some logging to your worker code so you can investigate which processes are shutting down early (and perhaps why).

Comment: does the worker read/write from/to disk or network? It sounds like a locking problem to me

Comment: @hansaplast it shouldn't. The parent process does write to disk. The worker does call a Cython-defined class method of an object loaded into memory by the parent.

Comment: @Blckknght will do! I had assumed it was arbitrary but that's absolutely an assumption that needs testing.